# Thread Detach In Linux System

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, pthreads, systems-programming

what I know is that detach( ) makes the main function not to wait until all threads have finished.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void *threadFunction(void *arg){
  cout<<"hello world = "<< *((int*)arg) <<endl;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int a = 10;
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,threadFunction,(void*)&a);
  pthread_detach(tid);

  cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
   
  return 0;
}
```

this is the code example, but why the threadFunction isn't being execute, because previously when I ran the code the threadFunction was called but after I ran the code again the threadFunction was not called. Why did it happen ?.

Also sometime i got unexpected value from the thread function,before i got 10 after i got random value

Comment: In general NEVER detach (and/or kill) a thread it is usually a sign you did not design your multithreading correctly. And more often then not you will get crashes at shutdown since you are still referring to variables that no longer exist. And this is happening in your code with the reference to local variable `a` in main

Comment: Also don't tag "C++" the linux kernel is "C" and in C++ we would not use pthreads but we would use std::thread/std::async

Comment: The reason you get different behavior is that main can finish before your thread is even scheduled. Or worse the thread still tries to print `a` after main has finished.

Comment: This code is not C, why have you tagged it as C?

Answer (score 3):

> what I know is that detach( ) makes the main function not to wait until all threads have finished.

No.  `main()` does not wait for threads to finish in any case, unless you explicitly code that.  The entire program terminates when `main()` terminates<sup>*</sup>, except if it terminates by calling `pthread_exit()`.

The point of detaching a thread is to get the system to clean up after it automatically, instead of waiting until the thread is joined.  But you can't have it both ways.  A detached thread cannot be joined, which makes it difficult to await that thread's completion.

> why the threadFunction isn't being execute?

If you do not see the output from `threadFunction()` then that's because the program terminates (as a result of `main()` returning) before that happens.  The easiest way to avoid that would be

1. Do not detach the thread, and
2. Do join the thread before `main()` terminates.

> Also sometime i got unexpected value from the thread function,before i got 10 after i got random value

The thread function's argument points to a local variable of `main()`.  The lifetime of that variable ends when `main()` returns, after which point attempting to dereference it produces undefined behavior.  The program overall will be in the midst of shutting down at that point, but shutdown is not immediate, so it may sometimes happen that the thread function exercises that UB.  Joining the thread would resolve this issue, too.

---

<sup>*</sup>Only the initial execution of `main()` has this property.  That makes no difference in C++, which disallows reentry into `main()`, but it makes a difference in C.

Answer (score 1):

Detaching the thread does not guarantee it will have time to finish running.  You have a race condition in the program.  Once `main` returns, the entire program exits.

Try adding a sleep to the end of the main program and see the difference.

Comment: A `sleep()` seem to help, but `sleep` is never the correct solution to synchronization problems such as the OP's.

Comment: Correct........